# Camera intent android

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

When I begin the camera intent I give it a file name I would like it to use. When I get this on the phone it uses the phones default file name. Which is no help as I need the image name later in the app.

Camera intent code...

```
public void onClick(View view) {
  String currentDateTimeString = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(new Date());
  System.out.println(currentDateTimeString); 
  filename = ("/sdcard/" + currentDateTimeString + ".jpg");

  Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
  File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), filename);

  outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
  intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
  startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
  filetype = "image/jpeg";

}
```

Comment: James, the only difference I see between the code I use and yours is the creation of the Intent.  Here is my line `Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");`

Comment: and does your work? with your file name?

Comment: yeah, one second let me post my whole function as an answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

James,

Here is the function I use to capture an image and save it to a location of my choosing (sub folder with my app name).

```
public void imageFromCamera() {
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
    if (!Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)){
        Log.d(TAG, "No SDCARD");
    } else {
        mImageFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"MyApp",  
            "PIC"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg");
        mTempImagePath = mImageFile.getAbsolutePath();
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(mImageFile));
        startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
    }
}
```

Comment: it gives java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data (has extras) }} to activity {