# How to capture a custom image size with the camera in android?

Tags: android, image, capture, android-camera

How to capture an square image in android?
I want to capture an square image (such as 300x300 pixel) by calling Camera through intent in android, how can I do this?

Comment: you are going to need to give us more context.

Comment: My context is: I want to capture an image which has width = 300px, height = 300px in android. how can I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

EDIT:
This is deprecated since API level 21.

Use the Camera.Size nested class

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Size.html

From the android reference:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html

> Class Overview
>
> The Camera class is used to set image capture settings, start/stop preview, snap pictures, and retrieve frames for encoding for video. This class is a client for the Camera service, which manages the actual camera hardware.

Make sure that the size is supported by the camera (and most probably it won't). If not, take a picture at the closest resolution and crop it or resize it.

```
Camera myCamera = Camera.open(0);
List<Camera.Size> sizes = myCamera.getPArameters().getSupportedPictureSizes();
```

To learn about camera intents, check these questions already in SO:

[Android camera intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729267/android-camera-intent)

[Camera intent android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5395674/camera-intent-android)

Comment: Thanks Aleadam, but I neet to capture a square image. There isn't any solution, isn't it?

Comment: @Nguyen : "*If not, take a picture at the closest resolution and crop it or resize it.*" I believe that's your only option (which would not be hard to implement anyway).

Comment: So, How can I can crop an image in android 2.x? I have no solution for this. Do you have any sample code?

Comment: Check the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846338/how-to-crop-an-image-in-android (specially the `com.android.camera.action.CROP` Intent)

Comment: the activity com.android.camera.action.CROP does not exists in android 2.x, Aleadam.

Comment: It does look like it's there: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/2.3_r1/com/android/camera/Camera.java#1192 . If not, check Shankar's or Dinesh's answers for alternative ways.

Answer (score 5):

Why nobody mentioned something like this?

```
Bitmap resultBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(sourceBitmap, xStart, yStart, 300, 300);
```

where sourceBitmap is original capture from camera and `xStart` and `yStart` location from where cropping will start. The result should have `xStart`, `yStart` in top left corner.

Comment: This would be a good option if the captured image is not too large for bitmap. I got an app that captures picture, but if I want to resize it this way, I get an outOfMemoryException, because the captured pic is too large.

Comment: @Opiatefuchs That would suggest the device is not able of processing its own image captures. Which makes little sense. Have you tried <application ... android:largeHeap="true">..</application>?

Comment: @JaroslavZáruba it doesn't mean that and it depends on several factors why outOfMemoryException happened on that specific device. Source bitmap should be scaled down first by some factor of two.

Comment: @JaroslavZáruba it doesn't mean that and it depends on several factors why outOfMemoryException happened on that specific device. Source bitmap should be scaled down first by some factor of two using BitmapFactory.Options, inScale parameter

Comment: @Ewoks If he has nothing else eating the camera then he should be able to load the bitmap in full size.